# Is it insecure to use a root user for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, security

I have an app that connects to different databases on a mongodb instance. The different databases are for different clients. I want to know if my clients data will be compromised if I used a single user to login to the different databases. Also, is it a must for this user to be root? to readWrite role will do the trick. I'll be co connecting to the databases through a java backend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward answer to this. It's about risk and cost-benefit.

If you use the same database user to connect to any database, then client data separation depends much more on business logic in your application. If any part of your code can just decide to connect to any client database, then a request from one client may (and according to my experience, eventually will) end up in a different client's database. Some factors make this more likely to happen, like for example if many people develop your app for a longer time, somebody will make a mistake.

A more secure option would be to have a central piece or component that is very rarely changed with changes strictly monitored, which for each client session (or even request) would take the credentials accroding to the client and use that to connect to the database. This way, any future mistake by a developer would be limited in scope, they would not be able to use the wrong database for example. And then we haven't mentioned non-deliberate application flaws, which would allow an attacker to do the same, and which are much more likely. If you have strong enforcement and separation in place, an malicious user from one client may not be able to access other clients data even in case of some application vulnerabilities, because the connection would be limited to the right database. (Note that even in this case, your application needs to have access to all client database credentials, so a full breach of your application or server would still mean all client data lost to the attacker. But not every successful attack ends in total compromise.)

Whether you do this or not should depend on risks. One question for you to answer is how much it would cost you if a cross-client data breach happened. If it's not a big deal, probably separation in business logic is ok. If it means going out of business, it is definitely not enough.

As for the user used for the connection should be root - no, definitely not. Following the principle of least privilege, you should use a user that only has rights to the things it needs to, ie. connecting to that database and nothing else.